# How to Save an Springboot Request to MySQL to Use After?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, web-services

I want to save requests to mysql that come in my springboot web service. (I want to use them after), How can I do that? What is the best way?

Comment: Enable General Log temporarily (remember that it is expensive). https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: @Akina I wanted to take the question sort, but actually I dont want to save all requests. Some of them which I will decided must be stored. I tried to save them in mysql as List<Object> but is doesnt accept a list full of object.

Comment: It's easy to delete unnecessary requests from the log. Adding missing ones is almost impossible.